# HTTP Request parsing

Tags: http, request

I would like to understand the usage of 'Transfer-encoding: Chunked' in case of HTTP requests.

Is it common for requests to be chunked?

My thinking is no since requests need to be completely read before processing, it does not make sense to be sending chunked requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the advantage to use chunked encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056227/what-is-the-advantage-to-use-chunked-encoding)

Answer (score 0):

It is not that common, but it can be very useful for large request bodies.

> My thinking is no since requests need to be completely read before processing, it does not make sense to be sending chunked requests.

(1) No, they don't need to be read completely.
(2) ...and the main reason to compress it to save bytes on the wire anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For an HTTP agent acting as a reverse proxy or a forward proxy, so taking a message from one side and sending it on the other side, using a chunked transmission means you can send the parts of the message you have without storing it locally. You avoid the 'buffering' problems, slowdown and storage.

You also have some optimizations based on each actor preferred size of data blocks, like you could have an actor which likes sending packets of 8000 bytes, because that's the good number for his own kernel settings (tcp windows, internal http server buffer size, etc), while another actor on the message transmission using smaller chunks of 2048 bytes.

Finally, **you do not need to compute the size of the message**, the message will end on the end-of-stream marker, that's all. Which is also usefull if you are sending something which is compressed on the fly, you may not know the final size until everything is compressed.

Chunked transmission is used **a lot**. It is the default mode of most HTTP servers if you ask for `HTTP/1.1` mode and not `HTTP/1.0`.